# Reading req.query from NextJS API route.js

Tags: next.js

So far I've been using the api folder inside of pages (/pages/api) and my application was working fine.
Now I moved **/api** inside of **/app** and converted each endpoint to a route.js file, but I'm having issues reading from the request object

```js
export async function GET(req) {
    const { name, number } = req.query; // req.query -> undefined
    // ...
    return NextResponse.json({ /*...*/ });
}
```

So I use that endpoint like this: **/api/check-availability?name=elem_name&number=20**
And I get this error:

`error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'req.query' as it is undefined.`

So, the question is... how do I read values from my request query?

*I tried logging "req" to see if I found the necessary prop and I tried reading the documentation, but NextJS docs are a little bit mixed up with this topic*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```js
export async function GET(req) {
    const query = Object.fromEntries(new URL(req.url).searchParams.entries());
    const { name, number } = query;
    
    // ...
};
```

I don't really like the solution, since I need to parse the URL to get the values. I'll try to see if there is a better solution; maybe I'll end up adding some middleware.